# How can I set to fetch only some branches from remote

Tags: git, branch, git-config

I have moodle project in git, and want to constantly update from the original git repository. However it has lot of active branches from which I need only two. Can I set in the gitconfig file to only fetch the two branch I need and leave out the others? I have this part of the gitcofig file, just don't know how to set it right.

```
[remote "Moodle"]
url = git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/Moodle/*
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can* limit the set of "remote branches" that get updated.  Simply change the line that reads:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/Moodle/*
```

to read instead:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/branch1:refs/remotes/Moodle/branch1
fetch = +refs/heads/branch2:refs/remotes/Moodle/branch2
```

(I have assumed here that the two branch names are `branch1` and `branch2`; substitute the correct names as appropriate).

However, as [Christopher suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24084405/1256452), any savings here are often rather minimal.  What git does "under the covers" is to transfer all necessary "git objects" in one lump (as something called a "thin pack", which is then modified on your end to be a "normal" pack instead).

Trimming the set of branches updated on your end can reduce the number of objects transferred, but packs are usually pretty compressed.  If the active branches that you omit include a large number of large files that compress poorly, you might gain more.  (However, if those branches get merged back to branches you *do* take, all the underlying objects will come across at that point anyway: you'll save now but pay later.)

Comment: Thanks this was what I needed... My goal with this was not mainly data saving, but I think in this case there will be quite a lot saving as there are a lot almost independent branches which won't be merged in the future... The main goal was to be able to see the commits flow [Sourcetree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) more clearly without the unnecessary branches, and it worked well there.

Comment: JFTR, to set or add remote tracking branches you can use "git remote set-branches [--add]", see: [git-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-branchesem)

Answer (score -1):

Git is a distributed version control system, which means you get the entire repository whenever you fetch by definition, unless you explicitly limit it the way described in [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24085552/877115). That's part of the design. "Fetching" the way you understand it (updating `<remote>/<branch>` references in your local repository), is just changing pointers. There is no centralized-version-control conception of "branches" here. Every clone of a repository is a complete state of anything reachable in the history.[1] Fetching is just a way of keeping two different repositories in sync.

To put it another way, you needn't worry about "fetching other branches". All your local is doing is updating its understanding of the remote's state.

If you want to see what's getting updated, look in the `.git` directory. They're literally files:

```
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/<remote>/<branch>
```

Footnote:

[1] technically there are "shallow clones" which don't include the entire history of a repository, but I'm ignoring them here. The vast majority of what we interact with on a day-to-day basis are complete repositories.